# How to make a simple Progress bar timer in Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, progress-bar

I need to have a progress bar drain from full to empty in 5 seconds and i want to be able to interact with other parts of the form application as well. How do I make this happen?

Comment: It is usually done with some lines of code which seems to be missing from your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will need a background worker or separate thread to perform this drain logic, or at least visualize it. Using the main UI thread will lock all other controls.

Comment: Winforms? [Timer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this block where the program creates a new thread and iterates through it. Each iteration the thread drains a certain amount from it with 'timeToComplete' and finally waits a second.

```
    private void CountDown()
    {
        int timeToComplete = 5; //Time in seconds

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
            while (progressBar1.Value >= 0)
            {
                progressBar1.Value -= progressBar1.Maximum / timeToComplete;
                Thread.Sleep(1000); //Time is 1 second
            }
        });

        thread.Start();
    }
```